# How to enable out of bounds memory checking on nvfortran compiler?

Tags: memory, cuda, fortran, nvidia-hpc-compilers

## Description and source example

Below are two simple, crude test programs that try to access out of bounds memory in cpu and gpu code.
I put the gpu example separately, so one can test the cpu example with different compilers and examine their behavior.

CPU example

```
module sizes

    integer, save :: size1
    integer, save :: size2

end module sizes

module arrays

    real, allocatable, save :: testArray1(:, :)
    real, allocatable, save :: testArray2(:, :)

end module arrays

subroutine testMemoryAccess
    use sizes
    use arrays

    implicit none

    real :: value

    value = testArray1(size1+1, size2+1)
    print *, 'value', value

end subroutine testMemoryAccess

Program testMemoryAccessOutOfBounds
    use sizes
    use arrays

    implicit none

    ! set sizes for the example
    size1 = 5000
    size2 = 2500

    allocate (testArray1(size1, size2))
    allocate (testArray2(size2, size1))
    testArray1 = 1.d0
    testArray2 = 2.d0

    call testMemoryAccess

end program testMemoryAccessOutOfBounds
```

GPU example

```
module sizes

    integer, save :: size1
    integer, save :: size2

end module sizes

module sizesCuda

    integer, device, save :: size1
    integer, device, save :: size2

end module sizesCuda

module arrays

    real, allocatable, save :: testArray1(:, :)
    real, allocatable, save :: testArray2(:, :)

end module arrays

module arraysCuda

    real, allocatable, device, save :: testArray1(:, :)
    real, allocatable, device, save :: testArray2(:, :)

end module arraysCuda

module cudaKernels
    use cudafor
    use sizesCuda
    use arraysCuda

contains

    attributes(global) Subroutine testMemoryAccessCuda

        implicit none

        integer :: element

        real :: value

        element = (blockIdx%x - 1)*blockDim%x + threadIdx%x

        if (element.eq.1) then

            value = testArray1(size1+1, size2+1)
            print *, 'value', value

        end if

    end Subroutine testMemoryAccessCuda

end module cudaKernels

Program testMemoryAccessOutOfBounds
    use cudafor
    use cudaKernels
    use sizes
    use sizesCuda, size1_d => size1, size2_d => size2
    use arrays
    use arraysCuda, testArray1_d => testArray1, testArray2_d => testArray2

    implicit none

    integer :: istat

    ! set sizes for the example
    size1 = 5000
    size2 = 2500

    size1_d = size1
    size2_d = size2

    allocate (testArray1_d(size1, size2))
    allocate (testArray2_d(size2, size1))
    testArray1_d = 1.d0
    testArray2_d = 2.d0

    call testMemoryAccessCuda<<<64, 64>>>
    istat = cudadevicesynchronize()

end program testMemoryAccessOutOfBounds
```

When using **nvfortran** and trying to debug the program, the compiler does not give any warnings for the out of bounds access.
Taking a look at the available flags for out of bounds access, both -C and -Mbounds options seem to be doing just that. However, they do not seem to work as intended.

When using **ifort** for the same thing, the compiler stops and prints the exact line that the out of bounds access was encountered.

How can I accomplish this using **nvfortran**?
I though it was a CUDA specific problem, however as I was creating the examples to create this question here, I found out that **nvfortran** does the same thing on CPU code.
Thus, it is not CUDA specific.

## Compilers used:

**nvfortran**

```
nvfortran 23.5-0 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp zen2
NVIDIA Compilers and Tools
Copyright (c) 2022, NVIDIA CORPORATION & AFFILIATES.  All rights reserved.
```

**ifort**

```
ifort (IFORT) 2021.10.0 20230609
Copyright (C) 1985-2023 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

## Steps:

**nvfortran**

I compile the examples as follows:

```
nvfortran -C -traceback -Mlarge_arrays -Mdclchk -cuda -gpu=cc86 testOutOfBounds.f90
```

```
nvfortran -C -traceback -Mlarge_arrays -Mdclchk -cuda -gpu=cc86 testOutOfBoundsCuda.f90
```

When running the cpu code, I get a non-initialized array value:

```
value   1.5242136E-27
```

When running the gpu code, I get a zero value:

```
value    0.000000
```

**ifort**

I compile the cpu example as follows:

```
ifort -init=snan -C -fpe0 -g -traceback testOutOfBounds.f90
```

and I get:

```
forrtl: severe (408): fort: (2): Subscript #2 of the array TESTARRAY1 has value 2501 which is greater than the upper bound of 2500

Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
a.out              00000000004043D4  testmemoryaccess_          23  testOutOfBounds.f90
a.out              0000000000404FD6  MAIN__                     43  testOutOfBounds.f90
a.out              000000000040418D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          00007F65A9229D90  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          00007F65A9229E40  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
a.out              00000000004040A5  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

which is actually what I expect the compiler to print.

Comment: Looks like `-Mbounds` might do it - https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/mbounds-compile-option/154453

Comment: Compiling with -Mbounds returns the exact same results, nothing seems to change.

Answer (score 2):

Bounds checking isn't support by nvfortran in device code and, as the following warning indicates, is disabled when using GPU related flags:

```
% nvfortran -C -g -traceback -Mlarge_arrays -Mdclchk -cuda -gpu=cc86 test_bounds1.f90
nvfortran-Warning-CUDA Fortran or OpenACC GPU targets disables -Mbounds
```

The out-of-bounds error is found for CPU targets:

```
% nvfortran -C -g -traceback -Mlarge_arrays -Mdclchk  test_bounds1.f90; a.out
0: Subscript out of range for array testarray1 (test_bounds1.f90: 23)
    subscript=5001, lower bound=1, upper bound=5000, dimension=1
```